# Programatically get connected Powerbank device information and battery capacity of Powerbank device

Tags: android, usb, device, usb-drive

I am developing an app which need to detect connection when any Powerbank device get connected using USB.

Whenever connection detect with Powerbank i need to get such information like *Brand name* , *Battery capacity* , *Manufaturer* etc.. of that connected Powerbank device.

For that i have created *Broadcast Receiver* to detect connection of Powerbank with my device.

**Code:**

```
public class PowerBankBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            // Do something when power connected
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            // Do something when power disconnected
            Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And inside *manifest* i added this.

```
<receiver android:name=".utilities.PowerBankBroadcastReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It is giving me *ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED* *toast message* whenever i connect and disconnect Powerbank device.

So my Question is: how do i get Powerbank device info when it gets connected ?

Also i reviewed one app on *[Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wikimediacom.powerbank&hl=en)* which exactly showing connected Powerbank device information. I wanted to implement same thing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt you can get manufacturer details as most power banks only use the power pins +5v and gnd of the usb port and does not use data pins at all. As for the app you linked, reviews says it all

Answer (score 0):

Most power banks for Android comply to the "Battery Charging" [spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/BCv1.2_070312.zip) by just shorting the D+ and D- data lines, preventing any USB data flow.

This way the Android device has no clue whether it is connected to a power bank or just to a charger plugged into an outlet on the wall.

Without a proper data channel you also cannot get information like brand name etc.

The App linked from the OP has *a lot* of negative reviews and comments - don't expect it to work properly. This may just be a clever fake to push ads or a crypto currency miner.